# Retrieving image data from a URL

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

Throughout my learning process, I've patterned a way to get images from the internet using this sequence of method calls:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
  guard let url = NSURL(string: "abc.com/someImage") else { //... }
  guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else { //... }
  guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { //... }
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.imageView.image = image
  }
}
```

`Alamofire` can do this too, and it's been the preferred way of doing any networking calls as far as I can tell. I understand the key points are that the abstraction makes the calls shorter, but I am wondering what other affordances it has for this particular scenario.